# generate chart min, max and average using Teechart with Html5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, teechart

We are using teechart(Html5 and JQuery) to generate a graph dynamically based on min, max values. The X and Y axis values are assigned from database. For example Y axis value should be 0 to 300 with interval 20 and X axis value should be time range between morning 12am to night 12am(like 12am,3am,6am,9am ....) .

Please advise me which chart we have to use for the above requirement and how can we implement using Html5 and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to take a look at both the [Summary demo](https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/latest/demos/intro/index.html) and the [Reference demo](https://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/html5/latest/demos/index.html) to get introduced on how [TeeChart Javascript/HTML5](https://www.steema.com/product/html5) works.
Also note the online tutorials and the reference guide can be found [here](http://www.teechart.net/docs/).

If you still find problems with it please [try to arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).